# recieve email, populate lead

Tags: web2lead

I am using a plugin in wordpress that creates forms and emails the info that is filled in. The plugin is called nm-webcontact. After a user clicks submit on the form, it will send the info to me directly. There is no way to make it save to a database. The plugin uses ajax to load the form, and to send the email without leaving the current page. I can set it up to redirect to a static page for a thank you, but it does that with a javascript redirect not a form post function. I can send the email to any address I prefer, is there someway to send it to sales force and get the info in the email inputted into a lead entry?

tldr; I receive an email with contact information, name, email, company, etc. I want this email to automatically get put into salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce has a very similar form builder called [Web to Lead](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web-to-lead.htm). This will give you an HTML form that will populate a Lead in your Salesforce Org. Just be aware that without modification you could be [opening yourself up to spam](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23705/can-web-to-lead-be-protected-from-spammers-without-additional-server-side-proces) in the future.

If you still want to stick with your resulting email, you can use a Salesforce InboundEmailHandler to parse the contents of the email out and create the coresponding lead record. See [An Introduction to Email Services](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com#The_Inbound_Email_Handler). Basically, during setup Salesforce will create a special email address that will pass the contents of the form generated email into an Apex class. From there you can choose how you use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Salesforce web to lead. Its simple just copy the html code on your wordpress site. Whenever a user will click submit button the information will directly go into salesforce.
In order to get email to you simply create a workflow on lead with "whenever created" option .and add email as action to it. In email templates do not forget to add the field values you want to recieve from generated lead.