# Need Help in test class coverage its getting 71%

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am trying to cover this class but unable to cover `url = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+lstDocument[0].id;` and pagereference method. Need help in increasing test coverage.

Class:

```
public class documentctr {

public String docName{get;set;}
public String url{get;set;}

public documentctr(){

    if(ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('doc') != null){

        docName =  ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('doc');
        List<Document> lstDocument = [select id from Document where DeveloperName =: docName];    
        if(lstDocument.size() > 0){
            url = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+lstDocument[0].id;
        }
    }
}

public pagereference returnUrl(){

    if(url != null){
        pagereference page = new pagereference(url);
        page.setRedirect(true);
        return page;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Test Class:

```
@isTest

public class documentctrTracker{

static Folder objFolder;
public String url;

static testMethod void firstMethod() {

    loadData();


    documentctr ob1 = new documentctr();
    PageReference pageRef = ob1 .returnUrl();
    //ob1.returnUrl();

    PageReference newPage = Page.pvdocload;
    Test.setCurrentPage(newPage);
    newPage.getParameters().put('doc','newFile');
    //ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('doc','newFile');
    documentctr ob = new documentctr();
    ob.returnUrl();
}

static void loadData(){

    insertFolder();
    insertDocument();
}

static void insertFolder(){

    objFolder = [select id from Folder where Type = 'Document' limit 1];        
}

static void insertDocument(){  

    Document obj = new Document();
    obj.Name = 'newFile';
    obj.FolderId = objFolder.Id;
    insert obj;


   // ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('doc','newFile');
    ApexPages.Standardcontroller sc = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(obj);
    documentctr ob1 = new documentctr();

    try{
    PageReference newPage = Page.pvdocload;
    Test.setCurrentPage(newPage);
    newPage.getParameters().put('doc','newFile');
    ob1.returnUrl();
    }
    catch(DmlException e){
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `Test.setCurrentPage(ob1)'; right above the 'returnURL' call in your test class?

Comment: yes but its not working.

Comment: I posted an answer. If it still doesn't work make sure to update your sample code so others (and I) can see what your new code looks like,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

Add the line below right above the 'returnURL':

```
PageReference newPage = Page.pvdocload;
Test.setCurrentPage(newPage);
```

Change the parameter line to

```
newPage.getParameters().put('doc','newFile');
```

In your code, change `System.currentPageReference()` to `ApexPages.CurrentPage()`

Comment: its throwing  Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [documentctr].getParameters() at line 42 column 9

Comment: You're right. My Bad. Can you please share with me the name of your VF page? (The one documentctr is the controller for)

Comment: its "apex/pvdocload

Comment: Just updated my code samples

Comment: pvdocload newPage = Page.pvdocload; it will throw Compile Error: Invalid type: pvdocload

Comment: I am sorry, Updated again, seems like I hadn't had all my coffee yet

Comment: hi kessel i have added the above code  but still it's not increasing the coverage.

Comment: can you update your original code with the updated one?

Comment: hi kessel i have updated my test code. please let me know if i any changes i need to do

Comment: It does not look like you changed the class code... only the test code. Change your regular code too, from `System.currentPageReference()` to `ApexPages.CurrentPage()`

Comment: sorry just forgot to update here. i have updated the class as well.

Comment: In your test code you seem to be setting Doc.Name but you query for Doc.DeveloperName...

Comment: name is required field in document so i am creating record using that field

Comment: If you query by DeveloperName, but don't specify a value on the document you create in test, you won't find anything in your code. That's likely why the line is not covered

Comment: there is a good discussion of how to get developerName on Document here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23705/can-web-to-lead-be-protected-from-spammers-without-additional-server-side-proces

Comment: If it did,  please accept the question and up vote so others can benefit

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are searching a document by its developer name in class and no value is provided for developer name of document in test class. Therefore, Please provide the same value that you are looking for and it's better to have logged in user / running user's id as folder id of the document you are querying for. So the snippet of insert document function will look like this:-

Document recordDocument = new Document
                          (
                           Name = 'newFile',
                           DeveloperName = 'newFile',
                           FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId() 
                          );
insert recordDocument;