# How to stop spamming leads from web to form?

Tags: custom-field, validation-rule, web2lead, lead-auto-response

We are trying to restrict the spam leads in salesforce coming from web-to-form.

we have a name field that can bring the spam leads . for example that name holds ---- 5xg7t52899 . How to restrict the above name with only having alphabets. yes we need to restrict numbers only. what is the validation rule need to write in Lead assignment rule to restrict numbers in the name ?

Comment: A regex something like [^\d]* or the likes. Did not test but regex should work well.

Comment: @Eric That's equivalent to `\D*`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson  Yea. I rely on regex101 to test. Not a regex wizard by any means. Not even with the basics lol

Comment: @Eric That's the right tool for the job, I use it too! It has a decent amount of educational content on how stuff works, you just have to find it.

Comment: Still we are getting spam leads after I use firstname equals \D* . I just put this on criteria , not in  formula to evaluate

Answer (score 0):

**New Spring 17 Feature**

If you haven't already you might want to add include a CAPTCHA in the Web-to-Lead form. Salesforce has added this feature in Spring 17 and this [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23705/can-web-to-lead-be-protected-from-spammers-without-additional-server-side-proces) digs deeper into it.